# Venn diagram shading

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble figuring out what the shaded region represents. The closest I've reached was $(X \oplus Y) \cup Z$, but that ends up including $X \cap Y \cap Z$, so that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Temporarily ignore the set $Z$. What does the **unshaded** portion represent?  Now, include the set $Z$ in your thinking, and ask yourself again: What does the unshaded portion represent?  Now ask yourself what the shaded portion represents.

Comment: Previous comment was the elegant approach.  The inelegant approach is as follows: With 3 sets, there are $(2 \times 2 \times 2) = 2^3 = 8$ possibilities re an element either is or is not in each of $X,Y,Z.$  Now, go through the 8 possibilities 1-at-a-time and ask yourself, is this possibility included in the shaded portion?  When done, look for some way of simplifying the expression of the union of those particular possibilites of the 8 that represent the shaded portion.

Comment: I got something that I think can be simplified, but I just need to check if it is right first. So the expression I got is (X⋃Y⋃Z) - (X⋂Y). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: I can't simplify it further, did I write it in the simplest form already?

Comment: Yes, that is how I would have written it.